# Read input from redirected stdin with python

Tags: python, shell, stdin

I have this loop that reads lines from stdin until a newline is entered, however, this only works from typing in the input. How do I get the program to read lines from a redirected stdin via the command line?

For instance:

```
$ python graph.py < input.input
```

Here is the loop I have to read lines from input:

```
while 1:
     line = sys.stdin.readline()
     if line == '\n':
         break
     try:
       lines.append(line.strip())
     except:
       pass
```

Comment: The program hangs at the second line of the loop and doesn't quit unless I interrupt it with the keyboard.

Comment: Are you sure your file ends with a '\n' line? You're probably running into an infinite loop here. It's likely that your file ends with a `''` line.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

As others have mentioned, probably your condition `line == '\n'` never holds true. The proper solution would be to use a loop like:

```
for line in sys.stdin:
  stripped = line.strip()
  if not stripped: break
  lines.append(stripped)
```

Answer (score 12):

Consider the following option

```
import sys
sys.stdin = open("input.txt", "r")
```

Answer (score 5):

ETA: Based on your comment that you're running into an infinite loop, you probably just don't have an empty line at the end of the file.

---

Use a [pipe](http://www.december.com/unix/tutor/pipesfilters.html) character:

```
input.input | python graph.py
```

If `input.input` is in fact a file rather than a stream, use [cat](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cat_%28Unix%29) to create a stream from it:

```
cat input.input | python graph.py
```

Comment: How is that supposed to help??