# How to implement ./program.py < inputfile.txt in python 3

Tags: bash, python-3.x

I am working in python 3 for few days, So experience is not so much.
I want to build a program which take input from a file through command line
in bash shell.
like

> ./program.py < inputfile.txt

and need to perform upon the input we get from a file.

Please help to implement only above thing.

Comment: There are many examples out there, please try to Google your question first.

Comment: I have tried many but can't find what I want or can't get what they did. If you know any url please give. Thank you very much.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27318022/read-a-file-from-redirected-stdin-with-python ?

Comment: Thank you Very much. I got it. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import sys

for lines in sys.stdin:
    print(lines)
```